# Write a regular expression to reject strings containing a period

Tags: regex

I'd like to find a regular expression that does not allow strings containing the "." character.

For example, `this_is!a-cat` should be accepted, but `this.isacat` should be rejected.

Comment: Do you need a regular expression? Many languages provide functionality for "string contains".

Comment: That's not a comma, that's a period...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this regex: `^[^.]*$`

1. `^` - beginning of string
2. `[^.]*` - any character except `.`, any number of repetitions
3. `$` - end of string

Comment: Was gonna post the exact same thing

Comment: I feel like my solution would be faster, and I also think it's worth encouraging people to think about the option of "what if I just need to negate the pattern?" in the general case. So many people just try to force regex to match the problem, where a simple transformation of the problem could RADICALLY simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just match on the character and then negate the result:

```
my $str = 'this.isacat';
my $has_no_comma = !($str =~ !m/\./);
```

(Note that the above is in Perl, but the concept should work in any language)

Comment: Perl has `!~`, eg: `$str !~ /\./`.

Comment: @Qtax: I'm aware, but I wanted to show the intent rather than use an operator which might not exist in other languages. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\.]*$
```

This defines a character class which matches all character except the dot. It also specified that the complete string from start to end much consist of character from this class.

Answer (score -1):

```
/^(?!.*\.).+$/
```

Should do the trick. Use a negative look-ahead to disqualify anything with a period (remember, it needs to be escaped as a `.` in regex means *any character*).

Alternatively, you can create a class that matches any character but the period:

```
/^[^.]+$/
```

The `[^` (characters) `]` means "*NOT* (characters)".

Comment: Your first example only catches the dot if it's the first character of the string. You mean `/^(?!.*\.).+$/`.

Comment: @Tim: Good call. I was trying to offer up an alternative to using a class, but you're indeed correct. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: -1 @ "use a negative look-ahead" for such a thing, and that one not even working if a line break is present.